# No puedo recuperar un valor de tipo fecha desde la base de datos

Tags: sql, reactjs, postgresql

Verán, tengo para empezar una tabla con los siguientes valores:

```
create table empleado(
  id serial primary key,
  nombre varchar,
  fecha_nacimiento date,
  dni integer,
  ciudad_natal varchar,
  fecha_contratacion date
);
```

Y tengo este formulario en una página de React que me crea un nuevo empleado:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createEmpleado } from '../lib/empleado.js';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { revisar } from '../funciones.js';

const CrearEmpleado = () => {
  const [nom, setNom] = useState('');
  const [nac, setNac] = useState('');
  const [dni, setDni] = useState(10000000);
  const [ciu, setCiu] = useState('');

  const ajuNom = (event) => {
    setNom(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const ajuNac = (event) => {
    setNac(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const ajuDni = (event) => {
    setDni(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const ajuCiu = (event) => {
    setCiu(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const introduceempleado = async () => {
    if (await revisar(dni, 1)) {
      const em = {
        nombre: nom,
        fecha_nacimiento: nac,
        dni: dni,
        ciudad_natal: ciu,
        fecha_contratacion: new Date(),
      };
      createEmpleado(em);
      alert('¡El empleado ha sido contratado!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="crear-profe">
      <h2>Introduzca los datos del empleado que quieres contratar</h2>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Nombre:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={ajuNom} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
          <input type="date" onChange={ajuNac} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>DNI:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            min="10000000"
            max="99999999"
            value={dni}
            onChange={ajuDni}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Ciudad Natal:</label>
          <input type="text" onChange={ajuCiu} />
        </div>

        <Link to="/empleado">
          <button className="btn" type="button" onClick={introduceempleado}>
            Contratar Empleado
          </button>
        </Link>
        <br />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};

export default CrearEmpleado;
```

Esto me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien. La historia es que de la misma forma que necesito poder crear un empleado, necesito poder modificarlo. Para eso último uso este código:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { updateEmpleado, getEmpleado } from '../lib/empleado.js';
import { useParams, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { revisar } from '../funciones.js';

const ModificarEmpleado = () => {
  const [nom, setNom] = useState('');
  const [nac, setNac] = useState('');
  const [dni, setDni] = useState(10000000);
  const [ciu, setCiu] = useState('');

  const { id } = useParams();

  const fetchEmpleado = async (id) => {
    const data = await getEmpleado(id);
    const datos = data[0];
    setNom(datos.nombre);
    setNac(datos.fecha_nacimiento);
    setDni(datos.dni);
    setCiu(datos.ciudad_natal);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchEmpleado(id);
  }, [id]);

  const ajuNom = (event) => {
    setNom(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuNac = (event) => {
    setNac(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuDni = (event) => {
    setDni(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
  const ajuCiu = (event) => {
    setCiu(event.currentTarget.value);
  };

  const modificaempleado = async () => {
    if (await revisar(dni, 0)) {
      const em = {
        nombre: nom,
        fecha_nacimiento: nac,
        dni: dni,
        ciudad_natal: ciu,
      };
      updateEmpleado(em, id);
      alert('¡Los datos del empleado han sido modificados!');
    }
  };

  return (
    <main className="crear-profe">
      <h2>Introduzca los nuevos datos para el empleado</h2>

      <form>
        <div>
          <label>Nombre:</label>
          <input type="text" value={nom} onChange={ajuNom} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
          <input type="date" value={nac} onChange={ajuNac} />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>DNI:</label>
          <input
            type="number"
            min="10000000"
            max="99999999"
            value={dni}
            onChange={ajuDni}
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <label>Ciudad Natal:</label>
          <input type="text" value={ciu} onChange={ajuCiu} />
        </div>

        <Link to="/empleado">
          <button className="btn" type="button" onClick={modificaempleado}>
            Modificar Empleado
          </button>
        </Link>
        <br />
      </form>
    </main>
  );
};

export default ModificarEmpleado;
```

Y me da esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tras cargar el formulario para modificar el empleado, cada campo del formulario me muestra el valor actual, pero no hace lo mismo el campo para la fecha.
¿Cómo lo arreglo para que también empiece ese campo con la fecha de nacimiento actual del empleado?

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué formato de fechas estás utilizando? Los campos de tipo `date` sólo permiten (hasta donde yo sé) formatos de fecha `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<input type='date' value='2020-11-14' />
```

Comment: Cierto. El formulario organiza las fechas como dia/mes/año, pero tanto react como SQL lo hace como año-mes-dia. Tengo que revisarlo a ver si logro un avance.

Comment: Puedes hacer un formato personalizado de fechas para traducir `DD/MM/YYYY` a `YYYY-MM-DD`. [Aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087128/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-format-using-javascript) un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo he arreglado. Para ello, hice estas correcciones en el código:

```
const f = new Date(datos.fecha_nacimiento);
let d = f.getDate();
if (d < 10) d = '0' + String(d);
let m = f.getMonth() + 1;
if (m < 10) m = '0' + String(m);
const a = f.getFullYear();
const c = a + '-' + m + '-' + d;
setNac(c);
```

Esto hace que se ponga el campo del formulario en el valor actual, arreglando este molesto problema.